# mutate function is not updating

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tbl_df` with several columns.  I am running a simple mutate on it to update a column, but the column is not being updated.

```
mutate(fltr, cat = "xxxxx")
```

`cat` is a column that is either `empty` or `NA`.  Filter is a `tbl_df`.  What could be causing this?  I have tried to put text in the `cat` column so that it is not empty or NA in case that was causing the problem. That still did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DavidRobinson pointed out, you are not assigning it back to the same object. To avoid reassigning we could use magrittr's *compound assignment pipe-operator* - **%<>%** :

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

fltr %<>% mutate(cat="xxxxx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think too that you might have meant %>%??

Comment: It is not a typo, it is `%<>%`.

Comment: I see. So why does this not seem to work?  data %>%
    filter(grepl("bis",ItemName)) %>%
    mutate(Cat = "xxxx")%>%
      print

Comment: Maybe: `data %<>% mutate(Cat = ifelse(grepl("bis",ItemName),"xxxx",Cat))`. Please add reproducible data to your post, and expected output.

Comment: That worked! So now my challenge is being able to do exactly the same thing but by looping through a list/vector or whatever for the search strings to apply to Cat.  Something like this where cat1 is a list of some sort.  `for (x in 1:length(cat1)){ 
  data %<>% mutate(Cat = ifelse(grepl(cat1[i],ItemName),"xxx",Cat))
}` I am open to any better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: No need for loops, use `|` - OR operator within `grepl()`, for example: `data %<>% mutate(Cat = ifelse(grepl("bis|bip|bin",ItemName),"xxx",Cat))`

Answer (score 8):

`mutate` doesn't change the tbl_df in place, it just returns the new, changed tbl_df. You need to save the results:

```
fltr <- mutate(fltr, cat = "xxxxx")
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am posting to the wrong area.  But essentially here is what I am trying to do:   I have a table and I would like to update certain columns based on the value in another column.  So I want to update column B based on the value in Column A matching any one row from another table.  To do the match I am using grepl.  I'm open to any other ways to handle such a task. I've been toying with dplyr, data.table and even just using for loops with a data frame.

Comment: Here is what I have so far:  <code>data %>% filter(grepl("SearchString",ColumnA)) %>% mutate(ColumnB = "xxxx")%>% <code> I plan to make this an iterative process for all values of "SearchString" which comes from another table/list/vector and for all items in the tbl_df data.

Comment: @user1991118 It sounds like you want dplyr's "join" functions, probably `inner_join`, if you're matching a column from one table to another. You should probably ask this as a new question, though. (Make sure you make it a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Answer (score -1):

Mutate is to add new columns(that are function of existing columns) to the existing dataframe. 
Here you want a static column to be added to the dataframe, for which i dont feel you need mutate. That you can achieve simply like :

fltr$cat <- "xxxxx"

But in case you want to add new column based on existing column, you can do :

fltr <- mutate(fltr, cat = "write your logic of converting column A to column B eg : Col_A/100")

Here "cat" will be the name of column you created.